# custom validation input type number angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to know how to set a min and max number in angular2 
when we try to limit an input text it's very simple we have to put 
any ideas about limiting the number for exemple 3 numbers

it work perfect on type text but with number I think we have to do a directive

Comment: If you are using `Validators` class to perform validation, you will need to write custom validators. Pleast post more code so I can see the way you perform validation.

Comment: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="myvar" name="name" minLength="0" maxLength="4" required />

Comment: You didn't post enough code, I wouldn't have time to look through it anyway, but this link was very useful to me, I also needed to do same thing you want to do: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-form-builder-and-validation-management

Answer (score 5):

Angular provide some *Validators* like *required*,*maxLength*.. but you can create your own Validator like this :

1. Create a fonction (this one take your control value, check if it's between 0 and 100. If it's okay, it returns null, which means no problems, otherwise you return an object with valid to false)

```js
function validateNumber(c: FormControl) {
  return c.value > 0 && c.value < 100 ? null : {valid: false}
};
```

2. Put your function as a Validator in your control :
   `new FormControl('', validateNumber)`

Comment: the min="1" max="100" doesn't work, if I put 100000 for exemple

Comment: I've updated my answer, it's more related to your question i think

Comment: Great. works perfect. if you want to add validation without deleting any exsiting one, use this: _fc.setValidations(validateNumber);

(_fc is a FormControl).

Answer (score 0):

You also can create some directives to manage your validator.

HTML :

```
<input type="number" maxNumber="999"[(ngModel)]="element.orderItemNewCredit" #newCredit="ngModel">
<div *ngIf="newCredit.errors && (newCredit.dirty || newCredit.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div [hidden]="!newCredit.errors.maxNumber">New credit cannot be superior than 999/div>
</div>
```

Directive : maxNumberValidator.directive.ts

```
import {Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, ValidationErrors, Validator} from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
    selector: '[maxNumber]',
    providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: MaxNumberValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})

export class MaxNumberValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    @Input() maxNumber: number;

    constructor() { }

    validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
        return control.value <= this.maxNumber ? null : { maxNumber: { valid: false } };
    }
}
```

And do not forget to add this directive into your module file.